# How to configure apache httpd.conf for Jboss deployments and nodejs webservice

Tags: node.js, apache, jboss, httpd.conf

My problem is, I have a environment with Apache and Jboss with a lot of deployments (WAR files). I also have a nodejs web service running on the same environment listennig on a port for example 4000.
How can I set up the Apache httpd.conf file for the endpoint of the nodeJS webservice?
I've tried to add

`ProxyPass "/web/service" "http://localhost:4000/web/service"`

and it worked but in this case I couldn't reach the Jboss deployments.

---

What I need is the following

www.example.com/web/service -> calls the nodejs webservice

www.example.com/custom -> opens the deployment custom.war